# why is an img in a h2 causing extra top padding in the other display:table divs

Tags: html, css, firefox, google-chrome

This renders the same in Chrome and FireFox so maybe this is intended behavior but it seems pretty screwy. Putting a image in the h2 tag at the top of a div with "display:table-cell" causes extra padding to the top of the other table-cell divs roughly the same size as the image.

Here's my test code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Chrome Test</title>

<style>
#col3 {
display:table;
border:1px solid black; 
}
#col3 div {
width:33%;
display:table-cell;
border:1px solid blue;
}
</style>

</head>
<body>
<h2>Wrong?</h2>
<div id="col3">
    <div>
        <h2>Heading 2</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. </p>
    </div>
    <div>
        <h2><img src="url" height="80" width="215" alt="heading 2" /></h2>
        <p>Suspendisse imperdiet lorem porta est venenatis viverra. </p>
    </div>
    <div>
        <h2>Heading 2</h2>
        <p>Aliquam laoreet diam sed ligula varius porta. Morbi volutpat ullamcorper diam, </p>
    </div>
</div>
<h2>Right</h2>
<div id="col3">
    <div>
        <h2>Heading 2</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam pretium, </p>
    </div>
    <div>
        <h2>Heading 2</h2>
        <p><img src="url" height="80" width="215" alt="heading 2" />Suspendisse imperdiet lorem porta est venenatis viverra. </p>
    </div>
    <div>
        <h2>Heading 2</h2>
        <p>Aliquam laoreet diam sed ligula varius porta. Morbi volutpat ullamcorper diam, </p>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Is this a bug? Can I avoid this behavior?

Comment: See my answer and let me know if i am lagging some where so i can understand your problem more clearly...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your divs are table cells and you don't set any vertical-align anywhere, so everything ends up baseline-aligned.  The baseline of a cell is the bottom of the first line of text (more or less), so the bottoms of the first lines end up vertically aligned with each other.  If the lines have very different heights (as in this case, because the image gives its line an 80px ascent), you get white gaps above the shorter lines.

If you don't want the cells to baseline-align, set their vertical-align to whatever value you want (sounds like `top` in your case).

Answer (score 1):

An h2 tag is a block element and may have some default padding assigned to it by the browser. Be sure to include a CSS Reset file (for example, [this one](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/)), to remove that unwanted formatting.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your given code i create the fiddle below -

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TtYn3/

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/TtYn3/embedded/result/

As per required image in H2 tag and the padding issue solved in other columns.

Answer (score 0):

Because you have display set to table-cell, your divs will behave just like they are in a table, and will stretch to the height of your tallest div (in each case, the div with the image inside an `<h2>`.

Second, you are using `<div id="col3">`.  Id is only to be used in CSS for when you will call that CSS only once.  You should assign col3 to a class instead of id, so that it can be used over and over on your page.

If you remove the display:table and table-cell attributes, your divs should shrink to their correct sizes.

Also, display:table-cell does not work in IE6 or IE7 (not that big of an issue these days, but still).

Answer (score 0):

H tags and P tags always have default top and bottom padding / margins and it depends on the browser.  I always set a class for them and set the margin to 0 and the padding to 0 unless I'm looking for some spacing, in which case I will set my own via css.

Comment: Agree 100%.  It's not a good idea to put an image in an `H Tag` anyway, you can always use CSS to position the image anywhere you want without having to add it inside an `H Tag`.